# Approaches in debugging segfaults caused by LLVM optimization

Tags: c++, c, llvm, compiler-optimization

We have a third party library, SPEC, that we use to test with. An optimizer pass in our local LLVM version causes SPEC to crash after SPEC has been optimized by our version of SLP Vectorizer.

I know specifically which file in the 3rd party library is segfaulting, but I do not know exactly what the transformation that is happening causes the segfault. I know that with SLP enabled, it causes it to crash. I also have the IR / assembly of the optimized vs unoptimized code, but I do not know which line in the library it actually segfaults.

I've been able to narrow down the file that causes the segfault in the library, and I know that it's a vectorization of a store that's causing problems (ie, if I disable that transformation, the library no longer segfaults). However, I didn't write the passes nor the libraries. I don't know how to continue. What approaches can I take to identify such problems?

Comment: Contact the third party, present what you are seeing.  Beyond that, this question presents too little specific information for any useful answers to be possible.

Comment: A segfault arising from (mis)optimization of C code almost always can be traced back to undefined behavior of the code.  In a very few cases it arises from a flaw in the compiler. Any way around, if the workaround you discovered is unsatisfactory then this is a problem that the purveyors of the library in question are best prepared to handle, and one which I suppose they would *want* to know about and handle.

Comment: LLVM's [opt](http://llvm.org/docs/CommandGuide/opt.html) has options to run and rerun with different combinations of passes, and to print what each pass does. That said, I agree this is too vague to be on-topic, and will vote to close.

Comment: I think I should mention that with SLP Vectorizer on, the code segfaults, but without it, it does not, which is why I didn't think this would be an appropriate question for the 3rd party library providers. Thank you regardless.